# Problem connecting QGIS to MySQL

Tags: qgis, mysql

I'm trying to create a new vector layer and store it in a MySql-database, but when I test the connection I get an error with no detailed information at all. If I give an erroneus password I get a message that says:

> MySQL connect failed for:
>   db_qgisgeodata,host=localhost,port=3306,user=xxxx,password=ppppppp
>   Access denied for user 'uuuu'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Because I get a detailed error message if i give the wrong login credentials I think QGIS is able to connect to the database, but there is something more to it.

The user has full permissions on the database. The problem is the same if I try with the root-user.

1. The user has full permissions on the database. The problem is the same if I try with the root-user.
2. The database is empty.
3. Windows 7x64
4. QGIS 1.8.0
5. MySql 5.5.28
6. it's no problem to connect with the database from other applications.

I guess I'm missing something quite obvious here, but I can't figure out what. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: What exactly happens if you connect with the correct passowrd?

Comment: I get a message with detaild error information that is empty.

Comment: Was this ever solved?